# Почему "cat" > "Cat" верно?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему это выражение возвращает `True`:

```
print("cat" > "Cat")
```

Ведь`C` стоит перед `c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Прописная буква стоит **раньше** в таблице кодировки, чем строчная буква, а значит её код **меньше**. А код строчной буквы соответственно **больше**. Поэтому выражение истинно, всё правильно.

```
for a,b in zip("cat", "Cat"):
    print(f'{a}: {ord(a)}, {b}: {ord(b)}')
```

Вывод:

```
c: 99, C: 67
a: 97, a: 97
t: 116, t: 116
```

`99` конечно же больше, чем `67`

Comment: отлично! Спасибо за ответ!